# Send content of text field to terminal, then display response in text label

Tags: objective-c

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction) charlieImputText:(id)sender {

NSAppleScript *keystrokeReturn = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"System Events\" to keystroke return"];
[keystrokeReturn executeAndReturnError:nil];

[progressBarText startAnimation:self];

charlieImputSelf = [sender stringValue];

NSAppleScript *sendCharlieImput = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell application \"Terminal\" to do shell script %@", charlieImputSelf]];
[sendCharlieImput executeAndReturnError:nil];

NSDictionary* errorDict;
NSAppleScript* script=[[NSAppleScript alloc] 
                       initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/applications/jarvis/scripts/getTextCharlieResponce.scpt" ]
                       error:&errorDict];
NSAppleEventDescriptor* desc=[script executeAndReturnError:&errorDict];
NSString* result=[desc stringValue];
self.charlieOutput.stringValue = result;
charlieOutput.textColor = [NSColor greenColor];
[script release];

[progressBarText stopAnimation:self];
}
```

Ok what this does is it sends what's ever in the text field to terminal and displays terminal's response on a text label. However, this does not work the way I want it to. It does not send the user input to terminal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the argument to `do shell script`. Also, this depends on there being a directory at the path `/Applications/jarvis/scripts`, which is kind of odd though not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

First: Does charlieImputSelf the value you expect?

Second: try passing an NSError into your `[sendCharlieImput executeAndReturnError:nil];` Do something like:

```
NSAppleEventDescriptor * ourRes = [theScript executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];
if (ourRes == nil)
{
    // error...
    [NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps: YES];
    showNSAlert( @"AppleScript error", [errorDict valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorMessage]);
}
```

(I'll leave you to provide the implementation of showNSAlert, or just use NSLog here...)

Comment: Yes, when I do this: 
NSLog(charlieImputSelf);

It does what I want. Any ideas??

Comment: Then see if Applescript is returning any errors to you (Like @Chuck mentioned, you probably need to change your applescript code to: "tell application \"Terminal\" to do shell script \"%@\""